# Shopify - Is it possible to show the Product Type on the order processing pages?

Tags: shopify

I run a record shop and use the Product Type variable to store 'CD' or 'LP' for instance.

This isn't shown in the item details of the order processing page, so it's not straight forward to know what item to pick, if we have it in stock in multiple formats.

Is it possible to show this information somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use line item property: https://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/page-specific/product-page/get-customization-information-for-products

Make sure your input is hidden and the value is product.type :

```
<input type="hidden" id="format" name="properties[Format]" value="{{product.type}}">
```

Don't forget to follow the steps to add the property line to the cart and emails.

Let me know if this works.